# how to add value from another array?

Tags: arrays, laravel-5

I have 2 array and this array structur look like.

array 1:

```
array:21 [▼
  8 => 5.2611505021202
  21 => 1.9708761602636
  4 => 1.9691954688805
]
```

array 2:

```
array:21 [▼
  8 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 10
    "details" => "Intel Core i5 4GB 1TB"
  ]
  21 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 14
    "details" => "Intel Core i5 8GB 2TB SSD Touch Bar"
  ]
  4 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 4
    "details" => "Intel Core i7-8700 GTX1060 8GB 1TB SSD Win10"
  ]
]
```

the problem is, how can u combine that array and make new array like this :

```
array:21 [▼
  8 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 10
    "details" => "Intel Core i5 4GB 1TB"
    "score" => 5.2611505021202 //value from array 1 and input the value to same index [8] -> [8]
  ]
  21 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 14
    "details" => "Intel Core i5 8GB 2TB SSD Touch Bar"
    "score" => 1.9708761602636 //value from array 1 and input the value to same index [21] -> [21]
  ]
  4 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 4
    "details" => "Intel Core i7-8700 GTX1060 8GB 1TB SSD Win10"
    "score" => 1.9691954688805 //value from array 1 and input the value to same index [4] -> [4]
  ]
]
```

is that possible ?, im newb very grateful if someone helps.
sorry for my broken english.

Comment: I think you have to write a custom function to create a new array, something not specific to laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is something inbuilt in [laravel-5.6](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers), but there is something in [laravel-6x](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#method-array-crossjoin) that would work in your case

but for laravel 5.x you have to write something by your own like below

```
foreach ($array2 as $key => $item2) {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $array1)) {
        $item2[$key]["score"] = $array1[$key];
    }
}

dd($array2);
```